# How to get the state of radio buttons in win32 c++ application?

Tags: c++, winapi, win32com

.
I am new to c++ and trying to get the value of the radio button for the use in my application.
But i am not able to get correct state of my radio button .
Here is what i have coded :

```
hDecRB = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Decimal Result"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,20, 80, 150, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                        hDecRB = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Binary Result"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,20, 120, 150, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                        hDecRB = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Octal Result"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,20, 160, 150, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
                        hDecRB = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("Hex Result"), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,20, 200, 150, 30, hWnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);


                       if(BM_GETCHECK==BST_CHECKED)
                       {   
                           flag=Button_GetState(hBinRB);

                           MessageBox(NULL,"CHECKED","sachin",MB_OK);
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           MessageBox(NULL,"Binary not checked","sachin",MB_OK);
                            MessageBox(NULL,(LPCSTR)flag,"sachin",MB_OK);
                       }
```

but when i click on my dedecated button to check the radio button state it shows me unchecked in both checked and unchecked conditions.. 
Please help me to get out of this . . .

Comment: Your if() statement compares two constant values, it will always be *false*.  You of course want to actually use the *flag* value, `if (flag & BST_CHECKED)`.  Consider using a C++ class library to help you write this kind of code, like MFC, Qt, wxWidgets, etc.  Petzold is essential reading if you want to use the raw winapi.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(BM_GETCHECK==BST_CHECKED)
```

This condition will always evaluate to false. That is why it is telling you the button is unchecked regardless of the button state.

In your case, you probably want something like this:

```
if(Button_GetState(hDecRB) == BST_CHECKED) {
    MessageBox(NULL,"CHECKED","sachin",MB_OK);
}
else {
    MessageBox(NULL,"Binary not checked","sachin",MB_OK);
    MessageBox(NULL,(LPCSTR)flag,"sachin",MB_OK);
}
```

Also you need to store each button in a different HWND. You are using hDecRB for each one, which is being overwritten each time you reassign it.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775986(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If your button was created as part of a dialog template (dialog resource), then you would use

```
if (IsDlgButtonChecked(hDlg, buttonID) == BST_CHECKED)
```

Using dialog template is much easier than creating button windows manually like your code does...